# jQuery UI - Open Accordion within Tabs with an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion

I´d like to open an Accordion within an Tab per external link. For example: www.demosite.com/site#tab1&2 should open the first tab and inside the tab the second accordion.

So far I get the specific Tab open with the following code:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
  }
});
```

For opening the Accordion I thin I should use the active Function of jQuery UI Accordion, but I don´t know, how I can use both.

Can anyone help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/bMeLL

Comment: The external link is from the same domain. It´s about cross-linking two sites

Comment: Oh misread the question. So you want some kind of syntax that opens tab and the accordion within its content? So #tab1&2 = open tab1 and, in the content section, accordion 2?

Comment: yeah, that´d be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the hash, to have both information in it.

Example 1: #0|1 will open first tab and second panel
Example 2: #1|0 will open second tab and first panel

For that, i created 2 functions: getHash and setHash.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var getHash = function(key){
            var parts = window.location.hash.substr(1).split(/\|/);
            var _key = parseInt(key) || 0;
            return _key < parts.length ? parts[_key] : false;
        };
        var setHash = function(key, value){
            var parts = window.location.hash.substr(1).split(/\|/);
            var _key = parseInt(key) || 0;
            parts[_key] = value
            window.location.hash = '#' + parts.join('|');
        };
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            animated: 'slide',
            navigation: true,
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                if(ui.newHeader.length > 0){
                    // A new accordion panel is open
                    setHash(1, ui.newHeader.parent().children('h3').index(ui.newHeader));
                }else{
                    // In case accordion panel is closed
                    setHash(1, '');
                }
            },
            active: false
        });

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            collapsible: true,
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                if(ui.newTab.length > 0){
                    // A new tab is open
                    var tabHash = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
                    if(tabHash == getHash(0)){
                        // In case current tab is the one in Hash, we open wanted accordion panel
                        // Make sure to parseInt hash value, because jquery-ui require an integer
                        ui.newPanel.find('.accordion').accordion('option', 'active', parseInt(getHash(1)));
                    }else{
                        setHash(1,'');
                    }
                    setHash(0, tabHash);
                }else{
                    // In case we close tab, hash is cleared
                    window.location.hash = ''
                }
            },
            create: function(event, ui){
                if(ui.tab.length > 0){
                    var tabHash = ui.tab.parent().children().index(ui.tab);
                    if(tabHash == getHash(0)){
                        // In case current tab is the one in Hash, we open wanted accordion panel
                        // Make sure to parseInt hash value, because jquery-ui require an integer
                        ui.panel.find('.accordion').accordion('option', 'active', parseInt(getHash(1)));
                    }else{
                        setHash(1,'');
                    }
                    setHash(0, tabHash);
                }
            },
            // Make sure to parseInt hash value, because jquery-ui require an integer
            // Remove the " || 0 " if you want all to be closed
            active: parseInt(getHash(0)) || 0
        });
    });
});
```

I did a fork here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9nKZp/1/
And the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9nKZp/1/show/

Comment: Absolutely great! just as I had imagined. Thank you

Comment: If I create a `<a href="#3|0">click here</a>` for example and click on it, it doesn't work, the hash only works if you place it in the address bar, any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `.accordion()`-call, you want to use `active: N` where `N` is the index of the accordion you want to expand (it accepts a number, but your fiddle uses it like a boolean).

Now you just need to provide the value of `N` rather han my hardcoded value of `1`. Building on your `ui.tab.hash`-method might work.

There are a few different methods of retrieving querystring parameters, but your URL is going to have to be something like `demosite.com/site?tab=1&accordion=2`. Do some research on how to get querystring parameters into Javascript variables.

[Here's a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/4ZchU)

Comment: This answer was wrong, I have updated the Fiddle and the answer.

Comment: Great, I will look into it. The only problem would be, that in every tab the second accordion will be opened. Can I do something, to pretend this?