# Linking to a section of an Accordion contained within a tab?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, accordion, nav

I am a relatively new web developer, as such, I have encountered my first major headache. Right, I'm attempting to access content within an accordion through anchor tags, the accordion is however, located within a set of tabs. the anchor tags are located within the footer of my index.php. All of this functionality has been conveniently provided by Bootstrap 3.

[image]

Essentially as far as I have gotten with this problem, and using stackoverfloooow I have solved the link to tab part of the problem, I did this using this script.

```
$(window).load(function() { 

    // cache the id
    var navbox = $('.nav-tabs');

    // activate tab on click
    navbox.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      // prevent the Default behavior
      e.preventDefault();
      // send the hash to the address bar
      window.location.hash = $this.attr('href');
      // activate the clicked tab
      $this.tab('show');
    });

    // will show tab based on hash
    function refreshHash() {
      navbox.find('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');
    }

    // show tab if hash changes in address bar
    $(window).bind('hashchange', refreshHash);

    // read has from address bar and show it
    if(window.location.hash) {
      // show tab on load
      refreshHash();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19983259/4711865